# Error while accessing facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure a Website URL in your app's configuration which matches the website/domain from which you want to use Facebook Login / the Graph API calls.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

  1. Choose app
  2. Go to setting
  3. Insert the correct URL